# Yaml file: build multiple artifacts from multiple projects within one repository

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm running into an issue with the project path not being correct and i'm not certain of the proper syntax.

Error: Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Here's what my YAML file looks like for the artifact creation:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Front-End'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: |
        '**/FirstProject.csproj',   
        '**/SecondProject.csproj',
        '**/ThirdProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'


# Publish the artifact
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: False
    projects: |
        '**/FirstProject.csproj',   
        '**/SecondProject.csproj',
        '**/ThirdProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/UI'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing UI Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/UI' 
    artifactName: 'UI Build Artifact'
```

However, this is not correct as it cannot get the proper project path. How do i syntactically say i want multiple projects? Is it not with a pipe delimiter and following each item by a comma? Or, do you think something could be wrong with the actual pathname, itself?

i tried to just create a single project

Comment: Could you add code for your whole pipeline?